# kubectl error querying EC2 for volume info

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I'm running Kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994 on an EC2 instance in AWS GovCloud. 
I can list EC2 volumes with 'aws ec2 describe-volumes', but when I try to create a persistent volume, 'kubectl create -f aws-pv.yaml', I get this error:

```
{
    "kind":"Status",
    "apiVersion":"v1",
    "metadata":{},
    "status":"Failure",
    "message":"persistentvolumes \"pv0001\" is forbidden: error querying AWS EBS volume vol-05dffe55de3ac725b: error querying ec2 for volume info: error listing AWS volumes: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403, request id:",
    "reason":"Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "name":"pv0001",
        "kind":"persistentvolumes"
    },
    "code":403
}
```

I've set these environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_REGION=us-gov-west-1
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/origin/master/ca.crt
```

Comment: This is probably IAM restricting what the keys can do. What IAM roles do you have?

Answer (score 0):

My IAM role, as the AWS user dvogel, allows me to successfully run the query 'aws ec2 describe-volumes', but apparently my permissions aren't passed to the Kubernetes api when I run 'kubectl create -f aws-pv.yaml' in the same terminal. I'm guessing I need to set something, in admin.kubeconfig?, to do this.

Comment: Just stumbled over this clue. btw, I'm using Govcloud.
Kubernetes probably can’t retrieve my AWS credentials. Even though I can use the aws cli successfully, for the most part, the following command to retrieve my credentials fails:

$ aws ecr get-login
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: “https://ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com”